# Reading Iframe Content in Iframe Load

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I just wanna learn how to read Iframe content in onLoad event of iframe and write it's content to the main page ? Thanks..

Comment: There is a way to do it, but it is klugey and requires the iframe to be rendering a page you generate/have control over. Is the iframe rendering content you control?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have struggled with same this past day. It seems to matter how you access the iframe. If you use `document.getElementById()` you get an Iframe object, which has no `onload` event. However, if you access through `window.frames[]` array, for example

```
var iframeWindow = top.frames['iframeID'],
```

you get a window object, which does have onload event.

*(ie uses the frame id attribute , but ff uses name attribute. So use both and make the same)*

You can then assign

```
iframeWindow.onload=function(){iframeContent=iframeWindow.document.body.innerHTML;};
```

Notice, since iframeWindow is a window object, you use window syntax to access content.

Comment: I did it but it didn't work for me. Could you please send me your example if you don't mind.
Thanks.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 
  function redisplay(){
  var content = top.frames['fetch'].document.body.innerHTML;
  top.frames['display'].document.body.innerHTML = content;  
  }   
  </script>  
  </head>
  <body>
<iframe id="display" name="display" style="width:600px; height:500px;border:solid 1px black;">
</iframe>
<p></p>
<iframe src="page-in-same-domain" id="fetch" name="fetch" style="width:600px; height:500px;" onload="redisplay();">
</iframe>
  </body>

Answer (score 11):

You can use this jquery function in parent page and it also supports many other function to add and remove stuffs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
         var $currIFrame = $('#Frame1');
         $currIFrame.contents().find("body #idofElement").val('Value i want to set');
          }
</script>
```

In above code: `#idofElement` is the element from HTML page in iframe whose value you want to set. I Hope it helps You..

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't know jQuery has such a function `contents()` and it looks really useful especially with iFrames.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery("#xiframe").load(function()
{
  var doc = null;
  try{
    doc = this.document || this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow && xiframe.contentWindow.document || null;
  } catch(err) { 
    alert('error: ' + err.description); 
  }

  try {             
   if(!doc) {
     alert('error');
     return false;
   }
  } catch(err) {
    alert('error: ' + err.description); 
    return false;
  }

  alert(String(jQuery(doc.body).html());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but actually the main problem is how to determine page load completes to get the content and write into main page content.

Comment: content "<html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>" or "<body>...</body>"?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('iframeID').contentWindow.onload = function(){
    top.document.innerHTML = this.document.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- parent document (the page on which the iframe is displayed)
- child document (the page displayed inside the iframe)

If these two documents are in the same domain, you can use the window.parent.document object in the child document's onload event handler to access the parent document.