# Capture iframe load complete event

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, load, dhtml

Is there a way to capture when the contents of an iframe have fully loaded from the parent page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Iframe Content in Iframe Load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229365/reading-iframe-content-in-iframe-load)

Answer (score 300, accepted):

### `<iframe>` elements have a **`load` event** for that.

---

How you listen to that event is up to you, but generally the best way is to:

**1) create your iframe programatically**

It makes sure your `load` listener is always called by attaching it *before* the iframe starts loading.

```
<script>
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.onload = function() { alert('myframe is loaded'); }; // before setting 'src'
iframe.src = '...'; 
document.body.appendChild(iframe); // add it to wherever you need it in the document
</script>
```

---

**2) inline javascript**, is another way that you can use inside your HTML markup.

```
<script>
function onMyFrameLoad() {
  alert('myframe is loaded');
};
</script>

<iframe id="myframe" src="..." onload="onMyFrameLoad(this)"></iframe>
```

---

3) You may also attach the event listener *after the element*, inside a `<script>` tag, but keep in mind that in this case, there is a slight chance that the iframe is already loaded by the time you get to adding your listener. Therefore it's possible that it will *not* be called (e.g. if the iframe is very very fast, or coming from cache).

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="..."></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById('myframe').onload = function() {
  alert('myframe is loaded');
};
</script>
```

---

Also see my other answer about [which elements can also fire this type of `load` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870185/javascript-onload-in-html/3870208?noredirect=1#comment57148725_3870208)

Comment: You'll have to make an Ajax callback to your server. The shown code runs client-side in the browser.

Comment: With this method you can only have a single function run when the iframe is loaded. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27824455/2111850) using `addEventListener` which allows multiple callbacks to run on the load event.

Comment: This approach is also vulnerable to a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) as the iframe could load before the script tag is executed.

Comment: The point of the answer is the `load` event. Now, you may use it in different ways. 

Of course you can use `addEventListener`, keep in mind this answer is from 2010 when it was *safer* to show the concept with the `onload` property which *worked in IE* too (again, concept with the least amount of code).   

Your suggestion of the `<script>` coming *before* the `iframe` can fail because `getElementById` is not guaranteed to find an element below the `script` tag.  

You may create the iframe programatically. That's the safest way to ensure your listener is added before the load event.

Comment: The load event doesn't work when you try to download a file.

Comment: explain what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that does not work in IE if the iFrame content is not HTML, e.g. PDF. See this: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/809377/ie-11-load-event-doesnt-fired-for-pdf-in-iframe

Comment: I ran into the race condition @Iest describes. My solution was to leave `src` and `onload` blank in the `iframe` tag, and then in javascript: `document.getElementById('myframe').setAttribute('onload', '...'); document.getElementById('myframe').setAttribute('src', '...');`

Comment: I can't find the reference for the `load` event of the `iframe` element. MDN only lists the `load` event for `Window` and `XMLHttpRequest`. Can anyone post a link to an authentic reference? I only found mentions of the event in [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/spec/the-iframe-element.html)

Comment: Note that if you absolutely need to add the load event **after** the `iframe` is already in the document, simply re-insert the `iframe` element (get it via query selector, then append the node somewhere) after adding the load event to it. Yes, this loads the `iframe` twice, but it's a workaround.

Answer (score 40):

Neither of the above answers worked for me, however this did

**UPDATE**:

As @doppleganger pointed out below, load is gone as of jQuery 3.0, so here's an updated version that uses `on`. Please note this will actually work on jQuery 1.7+, so you can implement it this way even if you're not on jQuery 3.0 yet.

```
$('iframe').on('load', function() {
    // do stuff 
});
```

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, `load` is gone.  Please use `.on('load', function() { ... })` instead.

Comment: If your using `jquery` or `jqLite` then this is the way to go!

Comment: "Neither of the above answers worked" now I wonder 9 years later what "above" was...

Comment: hah, me too, been a long time. but judging by the dates (my answer was 2014) it must have been gblazex and Gonza Oviedo's answers, because the others are newer than mine

Answer (score 23):

There is another consistent way ([only for IE9+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)) in vanilla JavaScript for this:

```
const iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
const handleLoad = () => console.log('loaded');

iframe.addEventListener('load', handleLoad, true)
```

And if you're interested in [Observables](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) this does the trick:

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

const iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');

fromEvent(iframe, 'load').subscribe(() => console.log('loaded'));
```

Comment: Is it a concern that my debugger stops at my breakpoint in `handleLoad()` before I see the iFrame render? I hope that's purely a rendering issue rather than a content loading issue.

Comment: how about to capture that event by jquery when the iframe is already there...
i.e : the iframe is not created by jquery.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the onload event doesn't seem to fire if the iframe is loaded when offscreen. This frequently occurs when using "Open in New Window" /w tabs.

Comment: also with iframes with display none ;)

Comment: I have an iframe which is display: none but the onload event fires after posting a form to it.

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1:** Add `iframe` in template.

```
<iframe id="uvIFrame" src="www.google.com"></iframe>
```

**Step 2:** Add load listener in Controller.

```
document.querySelector('iframe#uvIFrame').addEventListener('load', function () {
  $scope.loading = false;
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also capture jquery ready event this way:

```
$('#iframeid').ready(function () {
//Everything you need.
});
```

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrFzF/

Comment: I don't think that code does what you think it does. You can replace that "#iFrame" selector in your fiddle with anything and the alert still fires

Comment: In addition to @roryok, ready fires when DOM is ready, not the whole page loads.

Comment: ready is fired when the DOM is ready and js can be executed, not when the content is loaded.

Comment: $("#iframeid").ready triggers the function when the element is in the dom.
Not when the ifram has finished loading.

Comment: it just called once :(