# Simple Javascript not working: <div onload="alert("Hi");" >

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a really simple to `alert()` to pop up as soon as a div loads. Unfortunately it is not working, and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_1.4.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/alertjs.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="background_logo" onload="pop_alert();">
            <img src="mysiteLogo.png">
        </div>
        <div id="signup">
            <p id="instruction"> Get on board! </br> Enter your email to receive updates:</p>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/form-validation.js"></script>

        </div>
    </body>


</html>
```

And the JavaScript is just this:

```
function pop_alert(){
    alert("This is an alert");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4057251/2600397

Comment: What does it mean for a `<div>` to “load”? Do you want to wait for all images it contains to load?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3870208/1470607

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div 
seems it's not possible for div to have onload

Comment: If you want to be sure a dom element is loaded then put your code at the end of the body.

Comment: div does not support the onload event. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't attach `onload` to a `div`. Try putting it in the `<body>`:

```
<body onload="pop_alert();">
```

Answer (score 26):

It cannot be used for `div` tags. This is the following list it can be used on:

```
<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, 
<link>, <script>, <style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `onload` on a `div`. The best way to do this is to add a `script` element after the `div` to run the function.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_1.4.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/alertjs.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="background_logo">
            <img src="mysiteLogo.png">
        </div>
        <script>
            pop_alert();
        </script>
        <div id="signup">
            <p id="instruction"> Get on board! </br> Enter your email to receive updates:</p>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/form-validation.js"></script>

        </div>
    </body>


</html>
```

See [How to add onload event to a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div)

Answer (score 1):

`OnLoad` is used on `body or windows` not the `div` etc. If you want then use event handler to alert the pop up for example assign some id and use that to bind the event.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `onload` is a `document(body)` event.

**demo:** http://jsbin.com/benosofo/1/

> The onload event can only be used on the document(body) itself, frames, images, and scripts. In other words, it can be attached to only body and/or each external resource. The div is not an external resource and it's loaded as part of the body, so the onload event doesn't apply there.

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4057251/2213706

Answer (score 0):

`onload` is fired when the browser has loaded all content (including images, script files, CSS files, etc.)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Poor source I know.