# How to call jQuery function in <div> onload attribute

Tags: php, jquery, html

I tried to call jQuery function in div onload method but it is not working
here is my html code for calling the function in

```
<div onload="myfunction(value)">
</div>
```

and this function is call in jQuery but not working properly.

Here is my jQuery function calling:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        myfunction(value) {
            alert(value);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Please give me an idea about that how to call function in div load method

Comment: Function definition is `function Name() { body }`;

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159476/simple-javascript-not-working-div-onload-alerthi

Comment: Instead of adding "onload" attribute in HTML, use event handling on the jQuery side. $('#mydiv').ready(function(){ // code here}); (load event seems to be deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

### Example shows Div is loaded

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dynamic"></div>
</body>
<script>
$(function () {
    var div = '<div onload="myfunction()">Here</div>' ;
    $("#dynamic").html(div);

    $('div[onload]').trigger('onload');
});

function myfunction(){
    alert('Div is loaded ..');
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i want to call this function in append method so how it is possible

Comment: for example $(".mydiv").append("<div onload='myfunction()'></div>");

Comment: bt it is not work please telll me about that

Comment: Yes , this is possible ....

Comment: Please check code , i think this will help you ...

Comment: which code i will check

Comment: My answer  "Example shows Div is loaded"