# onload function doesn't work MVC 4

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to run a function when data load to table.Here are the code:

in View

```
<table id="DataLoadingTable" onload="showPage(1, 'DataLoadingTable', @(itemsPerPage))">
    <tbody>
@for (i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].ORDER_HEADER_INFO.ORDER_NO)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].ORDER_HEADER_INFO.PJNO)</td>            
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].ORDER_ROUTING_DETAIL.ROUTING_NAME)</td> 
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].ORDER_HEADER_INFO.DELIVERY_DESTINATION)</td> 
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].ORDER_HEADER_INFO.PRODUCT_START_DATE)</td> 
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].ORDER_ROUTING_DETAIL.TARGET_COMPLETION_FLAG)</td> 
            <td></td> 
        </tr>

}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in js file, i write this code:

```
function showPage(pageNumber, tableName, itemsPerPage) {
         var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        //show page
        var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1;
        var to = from + itemsPerPage - 1;

        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (i < from || i > to)
                rows[i].style.display = 'none';
            else
                rows[i].style.display = '';
        }
    }
```

The purpose of this code is to paging a page with 5 records/page. I use client-side paging, but the function onload doesnt work. The value of itemsPerpage=5;

I try to insert this function at bottom of view with the tag `<script>` but it also doesnt work.

Comment: Table doesn't fire the onload event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870185/javascript-onload-in-html

Comment: is there any other function that similar to onload using for table?

Comment: Why is the body's onload unsuitable? If the body loaded then the table has loaded too.

Comment: Its fine to use onload on the body, but if inside the body we had 2 or more tables, and each of them applies different function. I think it will be difficult

Comment: You can give each of these tables a class `class="download-table"` then you can get all at once and do a loop to iterate the collection `var tables = document.querySelectorAll(".download-table");`