# Using Common Header columns for multiple data tables of same type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 data tables with same columns containing data to be displayed in different sections. e.g. All tables will have columns like Id, name, marks,average.
I have created 4 tables with separate header columns names. I am now trying to remove redundant code so that I can some how write this as function and call it from 4 tables where needed. I am using onload event from html table

```
<table id ="t1" onload ="buildHeader('tableId')">
```

and here is my function

```
function buildHeader(tableId){
        alert(tableId);
        var rowStr =
             "<tr>" +
             "<th>Id</th>" +
             "<th>name</th>" +
             "<th>marks</th>" +
             "<th>avg</th>" +
           "</tr>";
        $("#" + tableId+ " thead").append(rowStr);
    }
```

Problem is this function never get called. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript onload in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870185/javascript-onload-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onload event is not fired for table. You can call the "buildHeader()" function on jquery ready event.