# Javascript to pre-select row 1 of html table on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following JavaScript code (found on Stackoverflow) to populate a div id ='article_title' from a cell value chosen from a table on the page.

**The issue I am having is that the code does not run automatically on page load - unless I click on the table.**

I would like to:

- retain the existing functionality ie run the code on clicking a row on the table

But I also want to:

- run the code on page load using row 1 (or any random row) from the table.

> ```
>   <script>
>  (function () {
>   if (window.addEventListener) {
>       window.addEventListener('load', run, false);
>   } else if (window.attachEvent) {
>       window.attachEvent('onload', run);
>   }
>   function run() {
>       var t = document.getElementById('table_id');
>       t.onclick = function (event) {
>           event = event || window.event; //IE8
>           var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
>           while (target && target.nodeName != 'TR') { 
>               target = target.parentElement;
>           }
>           var cells = target.cells; 
>
>           if (!cells.length || target.parentNode.nodeName == 'THEAD') {
>               return;
>           }
>           
>           var article_title = cells[11].innerHTML;
>
>           //Assign Article Title to text box
>           let h4 = document.createElement('h4');
>           h4.textContent = article_title;
>           document.getElementById("article_title").innerHTML = "";
>           document.getElementById("article_title").appendChild(h4);
>           document.getElementById("article_title").style.color='black'
>       };
>   }
> })();
> </script>
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript onload in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870185/javascript-onload-in-html)

Comment: Are you looking for `Element.click()` (simulates a click on the element)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Used the solution offered by [@coderLMN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67084883/1212412) to build the following code and add to the body section of the page. This works now:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var table = document.getElementById('table_id');
        var article_title = table.rows[1].cells[11].innerHTML;
        //Assign Article Title to text box
        let h4 = document.createElement('h4');
        h4.textContent = article_title;
        document.getElementById("article_title").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("article_title").appendChild(h4);
        document.getElementById("article_title").style.color='black'        
    }
</script>
```