# Hide iframe until it's fully loaded

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to hide the iframe until it's loaded to avoid the white flashing that occurs. **It happens all the time on Internet Explorer 11 and FireFox** Sometimes on Chrome if the page is slow in loading.

HTML

```
<div class="test">
<div class="hover">hover me</div>
<div class="cool">cool</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body { background-color: black; }
.hover { border: solid red; height: 40px; width: 40px; z-index: 1; color: white; }

iframe {position: relative; left: 40px;  }

.test { border: solid blue; position: absolute; height: 300px; width: 500px; z-index: 3; }

.cool { border: solid purple; background-color: black; }
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hover").on({
        mouseover: function(){
            $(this).next('.cool').html('<iframe width="370" height="215" src="//tsn.com" frameborder="0" ></iframe>');
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').hover(function() {



    }, function() {
        $('.cool').html('');

    });
});
```

**[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/LaL9nkup/9/)**

Comment: I think your question is going to be close to a duplicate of this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142837/capture-iframe-load-complete-event  You need to determine when the frame is loaded and then make it visible.  The other Q&A illustrates how to detect a frame loaded event.

Comment: @Kolban I tried  to hide iframe and show it when it's loaded, but it doesn't work. I still get that white flicker. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a91bmc4e/5/

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Updated

Try (v4)

```
$.fx.interval = -1000;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var frame = $('<iframe></iframe>', {
        width: "370",
        height: "215",
        src: "//tsn.com",
        frameborder: "0",
        style: "display:none;"
    });
    frame.on("load", function (e) {
        $(e.target)
            .fadeIn(1000, "linear");
    });

    $(".hover").on({
        mouseover: function () {
            $('.cool').append(frame)
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.test').hover(function () {   
    //
    }, function () {
        $('.cool iframe').detach();    
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LaL9nkup/60/

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to iframe stuff to be loaded with my page, I want it only to be loaded when called upon.

Comment: fiddle #50, It works on firefox, but on chrome I still see flicker on the first hover. On Explorer 11 I see it flicker every hover.

Comment: #56, still seeing the white flash =(

Comment: #60 still has white flash =( tested on Explorer 11. Anyhow, I solved my problem by adding a mouse over delay, so it won't show the div until 1 second has passed; thus, avoiding the flash. I really appreciate your time and effort to find a solution though.

Comment: @Newbie If possible , can post solution at OP ? You are welcome:) Cheers

Comment: what does OP stand for?

Comment: @Newbie Original post /  original poster / originally posted