# jQuery $(document).ready() as it is work or have different behavior with ifram?

Tags: jquery

They said : (http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(document).ready()
```

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

I was loaded several url via iframs and looking for the ready event.But my function not work correctly.I want make a overlay while page loading and after loading finished remove the overlay.

**Code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            #overlay{
                background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                border: medium none;
                cursor: wait;
                height: 100%;
                left: 0;
                margin: 0;
                opacity: 0.6;
                padding: 0;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 1000;
            }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="overlay"></div>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <iframe src="http://w3school.com"></iframe>
        <iframe src="http://w3school.com"></iframe>
        <iframe src="http://w3school.com"></iframe>
        <iframe src="http://w3school.com"></iframe>
        <iframe src="http://w3school.com"></iframe>
        <iframe src="http://w3school.com"></iframe>
        <iframe src="http://w3school.com"></iframe>        
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            var time;
            time = new Date().getTime();
            console.log(time);
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#overlay").css({visibility: "hidden"});
                console.log("fired");
                console.log(time - new Date().getTime());
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Updated:**

Even we remove the iframs and added delay loop with `php`.Then  loaded that page with `jquery` and the problem is still same.

```
for ($int = 0; $int < 100000; $int ++) {
    for ($int = 0; $int < 100000; $int ++) {
        for ($int = 0; $int < 100000; $int ++) {
            echo '<pre>'.$int.'</pre>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture iframe load complete event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142837/capture-iframe-load-complete-event)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will fire your `ready` handler when **your** page's DOM is fully-formed; it doesn't wait for the `iframe`s.

If you want to wait for the `iframe`s to load, you'd want to use their `load` event. To avoid race conditions, you'll probably want to add the frames dynamically:

```
(function() {
    var frameSources = [
        "http://example.com/this.html",
        "http://example.com/that.html",
        "http://example.com/the-other.html"
    ];
    var done = 0;
    $.each(frameSources, function(i, src) {
        $("<iframe>").on("load error", function() {
            if (++done === frameSources.length) {
                console.log("All loaded!");
                $("#overlay").css({visibility: "hidden"});
            }
        }).attr("src", "foo.html").appendTo(document.body);
    });
})();
```

That *looks like* it has a race condition (what if the `load` event fires immediately, before `$.each` is done iterating?) but it doesn't, because browsers run the main JavaScript code using a single thread, so no event callbacks can occur until the `$.each` loop is complete.

Answer (score -3):

you probably forgot to insert the jquery library. 
please check your console alerts / failures and add this into your head tag

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```