# event to check if the contents of iframe are completely loaded in Ext JS

Tags: jquery, extjs

I want to perform few operations after the loading of iframe is completed.

I have tried by adding the `afterrender` event listener, but after render event fires when the window is opened not when the content is fully loaded.

```
new window.Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'Popup',
            height: 630,
            width: 1050,
            modal: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            closeAction: 'close',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: "component",
                    autoEl: {
                        tag: "iframe",
                        frameborder: 0,
                        src: "http://www.yahoo.com"

                    },
                    id: "frametoShow"
                }
            ]
        });
```

Is there any event which fires when the content of the frame is fully loaded ?

I'd also go with jQuery solution as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do not use ExtJs and jquery in parallel. It just will increase the page load time. You won't get a real benefit, because their functionality overlapping.

Comment: You could just use plain JavaScript like it is explained in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142837/capture-iframe-load-complete-event

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to add afterrender listener but also get the element on load like this:

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: "component",
        autoEl: {
            tag: "iframe",
            frameborder: 0,
            src: "http://www.yahoo.com"

        },
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function () {
                console.log('rendered');
    
                this.getEl().on('load', function () {
                    console.log('loaded');
                });
            }
        },
        id: "frametoShow"
    }
]
```