# iFrame onload JavaScript event

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events, onload, onload-event

I have an iFrame, where I want to send a JavaScript command after loading.
My current code looks like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.test.tld/" onload="__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$bLogout','')">
```

But with this code the command isn't executed. What must I change to make it work?
Only Chrome and Firefox have to be supported.

Comment: does iframe load http://www.test.tld/ page?

Comment: Yes, that works without a problem

Comment: how do you know "the command isn't executed"?

Comment: Because I am still logged in. If I click on the "Logout" button on the site which will trigger the command I am logged out.

Comment: err, you are "logged in"? try: `<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" onload="alert('test')" />`

Comment: That's being displayed. Isn't it possible to log out with onload command inside of the iframe?
The code of the logout button on the site is <a id="ctl00_ctl00_bLogout" class="logoutlink" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$bLogout','')">(Logout)</a>

Comment: It is possible to do many things. Why in your case the to `__doPostBack` does not work - I don't know. Is function `__doPostBack` even present in the page?

Comment: Yes: function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}

Comment: use browser developer tools (F12) to debug

Comment: javascript is case sensitive. Should it be `onLoad` instead of `onload`?

Comment: The reason why you dont have jquery available is because its Telerik.  It uses its own internal jquery.

Answer (score 67):

Use the iFrame's `.onload` function of JavaScript:

```
<iframe id="my_iframe" src="http://www.test.tld/">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('my_iframe').onload = function() {
            __doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$bLogout','');
        }
    </script>
    <!--OTHER STUFF-->
</iframe>
```

Comment: maybe you can take a look at the native javascript version of this https://subinsb.com/jquery-to-javascript)

Comment: That also doesn't seem to work:

    <iframe src="http://www.test.tld/" id="loadTo">
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
  document.getElementById("loadTo").innerHTML = __doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$bLogout','');
 }
}

Comment: i changed my code to javascript. I hope this'll work, haven't tested it myself. @Peleke

Comment: Thanks, but that also doesn't do anything. Maybe it is not possible!?
The code of the logout button on the site is <a id="ctl00_ctl00_bLogout" class="logoutlink" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$bLogout','')">(Logout)</a>

Comment: take a look at this on http://liveweave.com/9ngqqd i have it working here (try changing the url from the iframe to load some big pages)

Comment: @Jasper 's answer was almost correct. It was only missing http**S** for the src of the iframe. HTML: <iframe src="https://www.example.com/" ></iframe> JavaScript: document.querySelector("iframe").addEventListener("load", function() { this.style.backgroundColor = "red"; alert(this.nodeName); });

Comment: @Peleke the reason your XHR is different is that it's not an iframe. addEventListener('load', () => { /* code when loaded */ }) is, I believe what you'll want for an iframe

Answer (score 27):

```js
document.querySelector("iframe").addEventListener( "load", function(e) {

    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    alert(this.nodeName);

    console.log(e.target);

} );
```

```html
<iframe src="example.com" ></iframe>
```

Comment: What's the difference between this way of adding the "load" listener vs the other answer where they set iframe.onload = a function?

Comment: @rasen58, they both do exactly the same thing. The advantage of `addEventListener` is that you can add `more than one event listener` to the load event. Please refer this answer for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348533/9695286

Answer (score 10):

Your code is correct. Just test to ensure it is being called
like:

```
<script>
function doIt(){
  alert("here i am!");
  __doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$bLogout','')
}
</script>

<iframe onload="doIt()"></iframe>
```

Comment: try: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <script>
        function doIt(){
            alert("here i am!");

        }
    </script>



</head>
<body>
<iframe onload="doIt()"  src="http://www.sdsd.com"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Ensure the URL being loaded into the iframe is allowed to be loaded, "check out the output in Chrome Development tools for loading erros". As if it's not allowed to be loaded the onload event will never be called. When I ran this code the URL "http://sdsd.com" did not have any restrictions and no loading errors. try it.

Comment: ensure the L in load is lower case, so "l" not "L" . so onload="doIt()" not onLoad="doIt()"

Answer (score -4):

**Update**

As of jQuery 3.0, the new syntax is just .on:

see this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27171097/1686442) and the code:

```
$('iframe').on('load', function() {
    // do stuff 
});
```