# How to make the iframe load before javascript get executed?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the value of the TAG which "id" is "token" from the iframe (id: 'myFrame'), but i get a "null" value displayed.

I guess the problem is that the iframe is not loaded before the javascript get executed but i don't know how to solve this problem.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Smth</title>

</head>


<body>

    <iframe src="script.php" name="myFrame" id="myFrame"></iframe>

    <script>

        var iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame'); 

        var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

        document.write(innerDoc.getElementById("token").value);
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if iframe is loaded or it has a content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249680/how-to-check-if-iframe-is-loaded-or-it-has-a-content)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    setInterval(function(){
         var iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame'); 

         var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

         document.write(innerDoc.getElementById("token").value);
     }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: Another solution would be is to use the on-load function. see this solution.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233928/iframe-onload-javascript-event

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, if I need to do it, is to add an `onload` event to the iframe so when it's loaded, execute the scripts you want to. For example:

```
document.body.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('myFrame').onload = function(){ 
        /* your code */ 
    }
}
```

What I do to avoid this kind of problems is to append the calls to my JS functions at the end of the body, so I won't try to reference a DOM element before creating it (the functions are appended in the head element).