# How to check iframe is loaded in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am loading in an iframe which takes some time to load. I need to check that the iframe has loaded completely and get the height of it

Can anybody tell how to how to check iframe is loaded in JavaScript?

Comment: Is the URL for the iframe on the same domain?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's load method to load iFrame and then in the callback get the contents of that. And depending on the content of the iFrame you can make further decision.

```
$('#iFrame').load(cbLoaded);

function cbLoaded()
{
   var doc = $('#iFrame').contents()[0].documentElement;
   // Get contents here:
   var content = doc.innerText || doc.textContent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the `script`, `img`, and `iframe` tags all support a [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event.

You can leverage it in vanilla JS, which is already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233928/iframe-onload-javascript-event), with either:

```
document.getElementById('#my-iframe').addEventListener('load', function () { ... });

document.getElementById('#my-iframe').onLoad = function() { ... };
```

But if you need an example of how to implement this in Angular specifically, you can do so in the controller or inside a directive's link function by using the `element` argument.

In a controller:

```
myApp.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var iframe = angular.element('#my-iframe');
  iframe.on('load', function() {
    console.log(iframe.height());
  });
}]);
```

In a directive:

```
myApp.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = 'bar';
}])
.directive('myDirective', ['$interval', function($interval) {
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var iframe = element.find('#my-iframe');
    iframe.on('load', function() {
      $interval(function() {
        console.log(iframe.height();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  return {
    link: link
  };
}]);
```

Comment: This worked for me once I put the controller contents into a $timeout(...,0)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you may listen on [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), the jQuery equivalent of document ready, and so add the event listener onload to the iframe:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  document.getElementById('ifrm').addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<p>Iframe loaded</p>';
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<iframe id='ifrm' src="https://www.wikipedia.org/"></iframe>
```