# How do I get the <title> from a child iframe to set on the index.html

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, title

Currently I have the following in my `index.html` file

```
document.title = document.getElementById('title').contentWindow.document.title;
```

But it makes the title blank instead of the title of the iframe.

How do I fix this?

[Here is my site](http://deepmotions.github.io)

Comment: which element is 'title' that you are looking for? GetElementById is used to get a DOM element that have an ID...

Comment: The iframe in which the title should be has id="title".

Comment: The code works, where it probably fails is that you're running it before the frame has loaded. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233928/iframe-onload-javascript-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the `title` of an `iframe` is as easy as:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeId");
var iframeTitle = iframe.contentDocument.title;
```

If you want to get the value of `title` when the `iframe` is loaded, execute:

```
document.getElementById("iframeId").onload = function() {
  var iframeTitle = document.getElementById("iframeId").contentDocument.title;
}
```

The `title` value is now stored in your `iframeTitle` variable.

Afterwards, you can replace you title value on your current page with this variable.

```
if (document.title != iframeTitle) {
    document.title = iframeTitle;
}
```

If you want to insert this code to your html file, add the following code after your content in your `<body>` element.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("iframeId").onload = function() {
      var iframeTitle = document.getElementById("iframeId").contentDocument.title;
      if (document.title != iframeTitle) {
        document.title = iframeTitle;
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not so good at Javascript, so where should I put every piece of code.

Comment: @DeepMotions See my updated code snippet above. Include this code at the bottom of your file before the closing `</body>` tag. If I could help you, it would be nice that you upvote my answer and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Nevermind, it didn't work locally, but it did work when hosted.

Comment: I strongly recommend to use and learn how the debugger especially for JS work in the browser. Such issues are easily fixed by the help of an debugger. Here is a [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) for the use of the chrome debugger. Have a nice day! PS: I like your music:)