# how to figure out new DOM is appendend or not using selenium/java/javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, dom, intellij-idea

In selenium-java, after switching to frame new DOM is appended on existing DOM, when I call findelement method passing xpath of append dom, it is throwing me error staleelementnoreference exception.

Is there any way where identify new DOM is appended or not using selenium/java/javascript? I have used explicit wait to fix staleelementexception, it does not work in IntelliJ(2018.3), but works in eclipse?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you are attempting to use Selenium with an iFrame and there is only one iframe on the page:*

You must switch to the new frame prior to calling `findElement()`.

**DO**

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")[0]));
```

To switch back to the main page:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Thanks Randy, I am able to switch to new iframe . after switching i need to get text of new DOM appended using findelement method. Do we have any code to cross check new appended DOM loaded or not, bcoz..new appended dom is big in size, getting exception in intellij ,but not in eclipse

Comment: Yes, use the iFrame's onload handler ( `documents.frames[0].onload = ...` )

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233928/iframe-onload-javascript-event