# How to run a function right after contents of an iframe are loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am currently using :

```
function printThing(){ 
    let link = parent.document.getElementById("oLink").href; 
    console.log(link); 
}

if (window.attachEvent) {window.attachEvent("onload", printThing);} 
else if (window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener("load", printThing, false);} 
else {document.addEventListener("load", printThing, false);}
```

To get a link from the contents of an iframe (which uses srcdoc instead of src) and print it in the console. This code will be added to some stored html before being sent to the frontend.

Is there a way to trigger this once the iframe content is loaded (ie without having to wait for other content in the app)? I tried replacing all the `window` with `document` but it doesnt work (it does nothing).

I need to access elements from inside the iframe and change their attributes.

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone will this wait for the contents? iframe loads with the parent, but the content (html) might take more time to render. Ill try and see

Comment: iframe.onload = function(){};

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iFrame onload JavaScript event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233928/iframe-onload-javascript-event)

Comment: @ChrisG no it isnt, my code needs to execute INSIDE the iframe. since it uses elements from inside it. Also I need for the content of the iframe to load, not just the iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

This method simply uses the `onload` attribute to invoke the function once the contents of the frame have been loaded.

```
<iframe id="some_frame" onload="on_iframe_load(this)">
    ....
</iframe>
```

Obviously, make sure the `on_iframe_load(_this)` function is in your JS code.
To explain further why we pass `this` into the `on_iframe_load()`, understand that passing `this` from a DOM element will pass the reference to the element.

```
<script>
var on_iframe_load(_this) = () => {
    _this.contentDocument.getElementById("something_in_this_frame").doWhatever(...);
}
</script>
```

**Pure JS**

If `HTML` doesn't float your boat, you can use `onload` or `addEventListener("load", ...)` and then access the elements inside the `iframe` using an element pointer and `contentDocument` (No IE?)

```
<script>
document.getElementById("some_frame").onload = function() { // or you could use `addEventListener("load", function(){...})`
    this.contentDocument.getElementById("some_element_in_frame").doThing(...)
}
</script>
```

Comment: so I can then use ```this``` to access elements in the iframe?

Comment: The code works. I just need to check if it does what I want (which might take time). Dont worry I never forget to checkmark answers (I upvoted since I learned a new thing from your answer). Also, I wanted to know if it was possible to call the function from the body inside the iframe and pass a reference to the iframe. Something like ```<body onload="func(this.parent)">```