# Jquery load event is not triggering in firefox(39.0), but working in firefox other versions and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have an iframe/img. I want to trigger the "load" event when the content is completely binded. In the fiddle, it should get a alert message.
So here my requirement is to trigger the event when the content is fully loaded to the iframe/img. Ie if that is an image, if I am not handling this, the user can see the pixel by pixel binding to the img tag.

[`JS Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykumarns/vbrnrmms/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/v/h60r2HPsiuM');
    $('#test').load(function(){
            alert('loaded');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe class="content_tag" id="test" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: @musically_ut Can you check the js fiddle?

Comment: Using FF 39.0 and it works

Comment: Using FF 39 and it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture iframe load complete event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142837/capture-iframe-load-complete-event)

Comment: Simple answer: You can't

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading

Unless the iframe src is within the same domain, in which case you can add a response header ( to that "dynamic src" ) called set-cookie ( with same data ofc ) then sample the client cookies - if the cookie is set you can tell content has loaded.. 

If you need more just let me know and I'll provide a more detailed example.

Comment: If it worked you would need to assign the handler BEFORE changing the src

Comment: @elad.chen Suppose I have the src when the page load itself, but it may take some time to load the external url to the iframe/img. So here my requirement is to trigger the event when the content is fully loaded to the iframe/img. Ie if that is an image, if I am not handling this, the user can see the pixel by pixel binding to the img tag.

Comment: @Pointy Are you telling it will not work?

Comment: @mplungjan changing that did not make it work for me.

Comment: OK I got it to work by using a modern version of jQuery -- http://jsfiddle.net/2wya34qo/1/

Comment: @Pointy that triggers way before the page is loaded

Comment: @mplungjan yes, you're right - it's probably coming from the "load" that happens on the iframe tag, or maybe the enclosing window load. I can't make it fire from the actual frame load, or at least I can't convince myself that it's firing from the frame load.

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS The concept of what I'm suggesting can be extracted from this clever plugin http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/