# angular.js bind to iframe's loading state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, angularjs-directive

how is it possible to have a boolean scope variable that is true when an iframe is loading/reloading?

JS:

```
$scope.item = {
  src :  "http:example.com",
  isLoading:false
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div ngclass="'loading' : item.isLoading">

  <iframe ng-src="item.src">

<div>
```

Comment: you could proceed by taking idea from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3142939/2435473