# Remove or hide content inside of an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Why i can't hide this content from an iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>contents demo</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="//api.jquery.com/" width="80%" height="600" id="frameDemo"></iframe>

<script>
$('#frameDemo').contents().find('#logo-events').hide();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Why this is not working?

Thanks.

Comment: it probably depends on how (and probably 'when' the content of the iframe is evaluated) . Try to hide the element after the iframe have been loaded:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142837/capture-iframe-load-complete-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the content of the `iframe` is on a different domain to the parent page. The browser security logic stops any attempt made by the parent to modify cross-domain content.

This cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

@Rory McCrossan is right.

The only workaround I can think of is to create another page on your own domain that loads the contents of `api.jquery.com` and then make iframe's src point to this new page you created.

E.g. Create a page called jqueryApi.php that has the following piece of php code

```
<?php
    $contents = file_get_contents('http://api.jquery.com/');
    echo $contents;
?>
```

And then make the iframe code to be `<iframe src="jqueryApi.php" width="80%" height="600" id="frameDemo"></iframe>`