# How to know if the iFrame has completed loading with javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I would like to know which callback to use when the iframe has completed loading.

```js
const iFrame = window.parent.document.getElementById('ReviewGeologueFrame'); 

iFrame.src = `/Review/GeologueFrame?id=${str}`;

iFrame.onreadystatechange = function (){

            if (iFrame.readyState !== 'loading')
            {
                console.log('iFrame has completed loading');

            }


}
```

When i tried the above snippet, there is no message in the console; what am doing wrong

Comment: iirc, the iframe should fire the load event

Comment: what is iirc ? not sure what you mean, mate !!

Comment: "If I Recall Correctly".  Try adding an event listener for the `load` event on the iframe.

Comment: `iframe.onload = function(){/* your stuff here */};` onload is your friend

Answer (score 0):

You could always try using some jquery.

```
$('iframe').on('load', function () {
console.log('iFrame has completed loading'); });
```

This works for me. [You might also want to look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142837/capture-iframe-load-complete-event). It is another Stackoverflow page where they discuss the same issue.