# What is the proper way to trigger iframe.contentWindow.postMessage after the iframe is loaded

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to post a message when the iframe is loaded in the page, but it doesn't work on `iframe.onload` or `iframe.addEventListener('load'`, it only works with using `setTimeout`

```js
const iframe = document.getElementById('iframe')

const postFrameMessage = () => {
    const params = {test: 'duh', ping: 'pong'}
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({parentParams: params }, "*")
}

//Dont work, no response back
postFrameMessage()

//Dont work, no response back
iframe.onload = () => postFrameMessage()

//Dont work, no response back
iframe.addEventListener('load', () => postFrameMessage() )

//Dont work, no response back
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', postFrameMessage() )

//Dont work, no response back
window.onload = () => postFrameMessage()

// Works fine and i get a response from the iframe
setTimeout(() => postFrameMessage(), 2000)
```

How do I avoid using `setTimeout` and trigger the postMessage when the iframe is loaded on the page? and maybe a bit of explanation why `onload`, `load` and `DOMContentLoaded` doesn't work

Comment: This seems to be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142837/capture-iframe-load-complete-event#3142939. I suspect point 3 applies; that the iframe is done loading before the event handler has been attached.