# Load iframe only one time, and hide it with toggle event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, toggle

I have different iframe, but it slows down. I want the iframe to only load,  when a button is clicked. And then hide/show iframe with toggle event.
Example of the code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button2").click(function(){
            $("#iframecon").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="checkbox" id="button2" onClick='document.getElementById("iframe2").src="/page1.php";'>
<div id="iframecon">
    <iframe id="iframe2" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the `change` event not the click; jQuery will handle it as "one" event trigger but standard JavaScript will add two event listeners so we should just use one (the change)

Note this assumes a hard coded URL in both these BUT I also added some "html" to inject in just for this demo.

Examples:

jQuery example:

Here I hide it initially, then toggle after I set the src value.

```js
$(function() {
  const htmlString = "<h1>content</h1><p>hi there!";
  const $frm = $("#iframe2");
  $frm.hide();
  $("#button2").on('click, change', function(event) {
    const srcU = "someurlhere";
    if ($frm.attr("src") !== srcU) {
      // just for this demo
      $frm.attr("src", "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(htmlString))
      // using an actual URL string:
      // $frm.attr("src", srcU);
    }
    $frm.toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="button2">
<div id="iframecon">
  <iframe id="iframe2" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Generic JavaScript:

Here I use a class and set that in the HTML so it is initially hidden with that CSS; then I toggle that class if the checkbox is checked to remove it or add it if NOT checked so the hide follows the X/checked shows, unchecked hides.

Alternative to this one would be to set a dataset value on the iframe then put CSS in to reflect the show/hide from that value such as `#iframe2{display:none;} #iframe2[data-showme="true"]{display:block;}` so any value other than "true" or not yet set hides it (order dependency of the CSS matters)

```js
const toggleCheck = document.querySelector("#button2");
// just to show the content IS added; same as src with a URL but I just inject some
const htmlString = "<h1>content</h1><p>hi there!";

function handleEvent(event) {
  const ifrm = document.querySelector("#iframe2");
  const srcU = "someurlhere";
  const isSet = ifrm.src === srcU;
  if (!isSet) {
    // just for this demo
    ifrm.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(htmlString);
    // ifrm.src = srcU;
  }
  ifrm.classList.toggle('hidden', !event.target.checked);
}
toggleCheck.addEventListener('change', handleEvent, false);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="button2">
<div id="iframecon">
  <iframe id="iframe2" width="100%" height="100%" class="hidden"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: there is also the possibility that you need to add to this code something that triggers an event when the iframe content is actually loaded, THEN show it.  Reference for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3142837/125981

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button2").click(function(){
            var iframe = $("#iframe2");
            if (iframe.attr("src") === "") {
                iframe.attr("src", "/page1.php");
            }
            $("#iframecon").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="checkbox" id="button2">
<div id="iframecon" style="display: none;">
    <iframe id="iframe2" src="" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Check the src of the iframe

Comment: This takes 2 clicks to initially show - that is OK but should be noted that the first sets the src attribute then the second (checkbox checked or not) shows the iframe since the src is now populated.