# before load function for iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

is there any way to capture the state of iframe when data is getting load? Onload is fired when all of content is load.

please help

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Iframe Content in Iframe Load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229365/reading-iframe-content-in-iframe-load). Well not exactly, but the info is there I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#frame').load(function() { 
                    // do work
                     });
```

This Jquery load function runs before function 'onload'. i also implemented this,as an alternate for before load because beforeload is not supports for iframe