# read xml response from iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading Iframe Content in Iframe Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229365/reading-iframe-content-in-iframe-load)

I am using hidden iframe to upload a file to a different domain.I am using following code:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target='myFrame' action='some_cross_domain_url'>
    <input type="file" name="myFile" class="upload_file_input"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
    <input type="button" value="Reset"/>
</form>
<iframe id = "myFrame" name ="myFrame" style="display:none"></iframe> 

<script>
    $('#myFrame').load(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
</script>
```

The upload is successful,but I can't read the xml response back from iframe.it just gives blank.is this a cross domain issue?
How I get the response from iframe..

Comment: looks like its cross domain issue,and `some_cross_domain_url` can only return xml.is there a workaround ??

Comment: If it is a cross-domain issue you need to user a server-side proxy. There is no work-around. This is BY DESIGN.