# Iframe document show basic HTML... getElementById null

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I spent about 5 days trying to solve this problem, and I searched a lot, however I couldn't find any solution for the problem.

Here is the code:

JavaScript (included in a simple HTML page eg: `index.html`):

```js
function createIframe() {
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "page.html");
ifrm.style.width = "300px";
ifrm.style.height = "300px";
ifrm.style.border="0px";
ifrm.id="iframeID";
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}
createIframe();
```

The page that loads inside the iframe (page.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<input type="text" id="textID" value="Test">
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript to access the iframe from the parent page (index.html):

In Chrome console I get page.html document as:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

With out having the other elements, so, when I try to get the text box or its value (using: `doc.getElementById("textID")`) I get null.

I am not sure where the problem is: is it in the code? or is it in the Chrome settings? or somewhere else?

All documents are on the same domain origin.

Note: I would like to use pure JavaScript.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: well when are you calling the code that reads the content? Is the iframe fully loaded?

Comment: Yes, it's. @epascarello

Comment: well I do not see the code that is waiting for the load.

Comment: Please take a look at the edited question @epascarello

Comment: I do not see how you are using window load event in the iframe to read the data,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229365/reading-iframe-content-in-iframe-load

Comment: @epascarello thank you for the link, you know what is really strange. When I use the same JavaScript codes in Chrome console it show the elements inside the body tag. The code doesn't work the same way in html page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason you are not creating the Iframe from this code is you are not calling the function.

you will need to call the function createIframe() to create the Iframe, this can be done using a button with onclick or with setting

```
  setTimeout(() => {

    }, timeout);
```

or even with taking the code outside the function declaration if you are going to use it 1 time only like this

```
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "page.html");
ifrm.style.width = "300px";
ifrm.style.height = "300px";
ifrm.style.border="0px";
ifrm.id="iframeID";
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
```

it's better if you call this function with a button or setTimeout.

hope this help

Comment: In fact I call the function, I edited the question to correct it. The iframe window and document is detected by the JavaScript code, that means it's loaded. The problem is that I can't  access the elements inside the iframe's page.

Comment: After I set timeout, everything went correctly, thanks Midz